# Regular Expression for matching domain when not containing www

Tags: regex

I want match a domain, when it does not contain www.

```
please do not match: http://www.example.com lorem ipsum
please do not match: https://www.example.com lorem ipsum
please match: http://example.com lorem ipsum
please match: https://example.com lorem ipsum
please match: example.com lorem ipsum
```

I tried this, but it does match all domains:

```
/(?!www\.)example\.com/g
```

How can I get this work?

Comment: You probably want a negative look-*behind*: `(?<!www\.)`

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you.